# How to solve this, 2 people working on same form

Tags: php

I've built a page with POST method form.
The form has a list of orders and tracking number for each order.

On this page two people are working at the same time, updating tracking numbers for order.

Example: when person 1 is updating the form with tracking number for order #126792 and click Submit, the database will be update tracking number for order #126792 and leave empty field for order #127299

At the same time person 2 is updating tracking number for order #127299, the database will update tracking number for order #127299 BUT insert empty tracking number for order #126792

You can see the form below in attached image, how can this situation be solved ?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Post some code. But essentially, only update non-empty values.

Comment: You'll have to update non-empty value & Add a button to remove tracking number for a specific order, Or add a checkbox next to each field and update the fields that have the checkbox checked.

Comment: Instead I would suggest updating only changed values by keeping track of the values at form load. It's a bit more invasive and can cause overwrites in case they both change the same field/value, but generally more flexible in the sense that it allows values to be deleted and doesn't revert already set values. Much like a git merge.

Comment: dont know what database you use but for mysql add " WHERE field IS NULL OR field = '' " to the query thats updating the table

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad since it really depends on how your system and your users behave. Also, without you providing any code, I can't really answer with code.

However, I can provide a kind of decision alghorithm that might help you...

### Questions:

1. **Can the same record be updated by 2 different users at the same time?**

   - **No**: Proceed to 2
   - **Yes**: Solution C, D or E
2. **Can a user update 2 orders at the same time?**

   - **No:** Solution A
   - **Yes:** Proceed to 3
3. **Are empty values meaningful?** (that is, can a user update/delete a record by submitting an empty "tracking code"?)

   - **No:** Solution B
   - **Yes:** Solution C, D or E

---

### Solutions:

A. Change the frontend so that the **user can only update 1 order BOX at a time**

B. **Ignore empty/false/null values** in the backend.

C. **Lock** the records being edited:

1. User selects the records to update and informs the backend
2. The backend locks the records being updated until the user updates it or the "update time" expires

D. Use a **version system**: make each update a new version of the records and if a conflict arises, ask the last user that tried to update to resolve before committing the data.

E. Make the **records "real time"** (with short polling or long polling)

---

NOTE: Keep in mind that this assumes users are "smart", that is, they only behave in a predictable way (that you can specify without code) and they will oblige and won't try funny stuff.